# Google Sheets, getting information from multiple different sheets with different lengths to populate structure

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to build a document which will make it easier for my staff to make 'Email Structure' essentially with a series of dropdown choices and when they select an option, different information populates the cells from another sheet within the document. The most important thing is that it brings in the product name and the description of the product across all four columns (the product name, the price, the product type and the product description).

I have used StackOverflow research to try a few different combinations so far but not much has worked.

You can see what I am attempting by seeing the sheet 'Email Structure' on the following Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExQGxxesv64OZJc4uoHVMLkaOCFUVsIQWVBPMuOB8xE/edit?usp=sharing

I am eventually going to have thousands of products across different sheets to pick from, so any advice on this would be really great so I can learn and understand how to do this before cascading it to apply across many more areas.

Options I have tried in cell C4 of sheet 'Email Structure':

=VLOOKUP(B4, All Products!B6:C65, 2,FALSE)

=IF(B4="Gaming Energy",VLOOKUP(B4,All Products!B6:B12,2,FALSE),IF(B4="Pro Series",VLOOKUP(B4,All Products!B27:B36,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B4,All Products!B51:B65,2,FALSE)))

=IF(B4="Gaming Energy",VLOOKUP(B4,A6:B12,2,FALSE),IF(B4="Pro Series",VLOOKUP(B4,A27:B36,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B4,A51:B65,2,FALSE)))

=QUERY('Gaming Energy'!B6:E12,"select B,C,D,E where 'Product'='"&B4&"'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to have all products in one sheet and then distribute them in the others based on filters??

If you have everything in 'All Products', you can do a Query similar to your last one:

```
=QUERY('All Products'!B:E,"WHERE C = '"&B4&"'")
```

Comment: Yes, they will all be in the same sheet, 'All Products', is that query above the full query?

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your question. Have you tried the formula I proposed?, Is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Sorry my response was unclear - thank you your solution helped, but not for 'Pro Series' and 'Other Products'

Comment: That's because your dropdown doesn't match exactly your types in C column of All Products. Would you expect the Query to go to the specific sheet? Or where do you expect to fetch your informationa

Comment: Thank you very much - you have been very helpful!